# "How to build a user interface similar to Windows Explorer in Java?"

Tags: java, user-interface, windows-explorer

I need develop a Java UI similar to windows explorer.
The interface should have itens like icons and drag'n drop feature.

Comment: you are welcome to mod mine rather than starting from scratch: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/jutils-jsg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you can look at SWT examples, http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/swt/swt-file-browser.shtml and http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTFileBrowser.htm

Answer (score 1):

These things are all possible in Java, but your question is much too vague for a specific answer.  You will have to learn a UI toolkit such as AWT, Swing, SWT, etc.  The toolkit will provide components from which you can build such a UI.  You will probably even find pre-built systems if you do a little research with your favorite search engine.

SO is a place where you can ask specific questions that need specific answers while you are learning the UI toolkit(s).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should google "Java look and feel" here is a link that can help you: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, you may want to look at the source code for [`javax.swing.JFileChooser`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html). The JFileChooser class produces much of what you're looking for, though it's designed for things like "open file(s)" and "save file" dialogs, rather than an explorer window.

The source for JFileChooser is available in the JDK distribution from Sun, or you can [find it online](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/JFileChooser-source.html).